# Laptop get hanged after the 30 minutes of proper startup

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze

I have got below laptop configuration:

```
DELL Insiprion    
Windows 7 Home premium
Ram 4 GB
Hard Disk 500 GB
Processor Intel core i3
```

My Laptop was working fine till this problem occurs, suddenly from last two days, whenever I start my laptop it starts perfectly and after working of 30 minutes or 1 hours it gets hanged and then there is no way to do proper shutdown.

Finally, I have to do Hard Shutdown by pressing the power buttom. I have tried a to restart the laptop and problem is same after using 30 min to 1 hour it get hanged.

I have run CHKDSK but no luck, I though there may be heating issue to I bought cooling pad.

Please suggest how to fix this issue, do I need to reinstall windows 7 or my hard drive/RAM is having problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the eventlog say anything interesting?

Comment: No there is nothing much over there, I tried to view that....any other place were I see something.

Comment: Really, there is so many things it could be (overheating, bad motherboard, bad driver, BIOS settings mucked up, Windows COM+ issue, etc etc etc), that without a little bit more information there isn't much that can be troubleshooted.

Comment: Ok...Thanks, can you please tell me what more information is required. I will try to get it and will post in my question.

Comment: Mostly, troubleshooting this issue will be down to process of elimination.  Try running the dell diagnostics on your computer, they can be accessed on most Inspirons by pressing F12 on boot and selecting the diagnostics start up option.

Comment: yeah I tried to do that..actually there are two parts 1 and 2, I checked 1 got finished successfully and when it was running 2 part after 30% completion laptop got shutdown automatically...don't know what happened..can I run this tool when system is up.

Comment: When it hangs, does your mouse pointer stop working?  If not, it's probably hard drive related.  If it does, it's probably RAM or other hardware. Have you cleaned the intake and exhaust vents?  Does it lock if you leave it sitting idle for an hour or more, or is it only happening while you're using it?  How about sitting idle in Safe Mode?

Comment: My mouse pointer goes on waiting icon..however I can move my mouse, how to clean intake and exhaust vents? yes even I don't work also it gets hanged, however mostly get hanged while working...in safe mode without network waorks fine....please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/) for your device temperature about CPU, Mainboard, Ram and etc. I think is your device very hot maybe solve your problem with this way. I think you should find final bios update and install it. If the ways aren't useful, your device hardware has a problem about Ram or VGA.

Comment: agree. @M.S check the air flow of cpu fan. if it is so hot you have fan problem as I had before in my Inspiron. try to use "Cool pad"s

Answer (score 0):

Please list the following details:

- List of recently installed updates (past week) and their install dates.
- List of any driver updates you have done.
- List of any delayed start services (in win 7 type (services) in the start menu, an image of two cogs named services should be in the list, you can gather info here).
- List of items in the startup tab of msconfig.
- Version of Antivirus software you are using.
- Download speedfan from http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php and use the s.m.a.r.t. function, click "perform an in-depth online analysis of this hard disk" and then, at the bottom of the page that opens, click on the "link to this report" link, then post that here.

Please also provide a detailed description of the freezing issue, i.e. when it freezes can you move the mouse, does it blue screen, is it terribly slow or completely unresponsive? Do you get artefacts on the screen, do you get artefacts in sound? Any and all additional info is useful for a diagnosis.